# the eclipse launcher does not exist

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

I downloaded the eclipse from the official site then i ruining the command `sudo ./eclipse-inst` i choose the installation folder in /user  then the installation is completed with success and i tested a hello example and it's work . But i didn't find th launch icon on my application.
i created a file eclipe.desktop `sudo nano /usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop` and add this config . but i still have the same problem

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Eclipse IDE
Comment=Eclipse IDE
Exec=/usr/eclipse/eclipse
Icon=/usr/eclipse/icon.xpm
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=false
```

how can i launch eclipse and solve this problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i used this command and it's work `sudo chmod 775 -R/root/`

Comment: not related to eclipse icon

Answer (score 1):

if you want you have a  easier way to install eclipse on GNU/Linux with the Eclispe Installer, you will can also update it in a easier way.
[Eclipse installer on Linux](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/installer)

Comment: that exactly what i did but after flowing this step i don't found the icon of launching

Comment: I 'm talking about the Eclipse tool box installer, like the JetBrain's toolbox for example... not only the  installer for IDE Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you add this line your config file and save it. This should work , as it solved my problem.

```
StartupWMClass=Eclipse
```